Why is JComboBox's background gray with Windows L&F?
Here's a problem. We have a custom combo box popup. It's a simple anonymous extension that returns a custom ComboPopup implementation
If I extend WindowsComboBoxUI, the current selection's background is light-gray (seemingly, 225,225,225). It's good, it's what our users are used to
If I extend BasicComboBoxUI, the current selection's background is white. Bad, that would make custom combo boxes stand apart from OOB combo boxes
We could extend WindowsComboBoxUI, but since Java 9, it's in a restricted module. So any upgrades from Java 8, which we currently have, would be trickier. I'd like to avoid referencing that class (or anything from that package)
So what I need is to find out how WindowsComboBoxUI ensures the current selection background is gray and mimic that behavior in my extension
It seems

the painted ListCellRenderer is transparent (its opaque property is set to false)
the CellRendererPane, to which it's added to, is also transparent
but the combo, to which the pane is added to, is not; its background color is white (255,255,255) (which is, I assume, the color that shows through)

But it seems it should be the case with and without WindowsComboBoxUI. Put a breakpoint at javax.swing.JComponent#paint with the condition getClass().getName().contains("Renderer"), and you'll see that by the time the renderer panel is painted (com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsComboBoxUI$WindowsComboBoxRenderer), it's transparent, its parent (the renderer pane) is also transparent, its grandparent (the combo), on the other hand, is not and has a white background. So even in Test 1 the current value is expected to be displayed against a white backdrop. But it never happens
Test 1. Everything's fine, but we reference com.sun
package demos.combo;

import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsComboBoxUI;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComboBoxUI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SimpleComboDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple combo demo");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        ComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
        JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>(model);
        combo.setUI(comboUi());
        comboItems().forEach(combo::addItem);
        mainPanel.add(combo);
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static ComboBoxUI comboUi() {
        return new WindowsComboBoxUI() {
            // imagine I need to override something here, e.g. createPopup()
        };
    }

    private static List<String> comboItems() {
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add("Pen");
        items.add("Pencil");
        items.add("Eraser");
        return items;
    }
}

combo, gray background
Test 2. com.sun is not referenced, but the background is white (so is the foreground)
package demos.combo;

import di.ListCellRenderers;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComboBoxUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SimpleComboDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple combo demo");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        ComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
        JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>(model);
        // Notice this line. I have to set a custom renderer since BasicComboBoxRenderer is opaque=true, will be painted blue (List.selectionBackground)
        combo.setRenderer(ListCellRenderers.renderer(Object::toString));
        combo.setUI(comboUi());
        comboItems().forEach(combo::addItem);
        mainPanel.add(combo);
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static ComboBoxUI comboUi() {
        return new BasicComboBoxUI() {
            // imagine I need to override something here, e.g. createPopup()
            // btw, if you believe overriding createRenderer() will help, it won't
        };
    }

    private static List<String> comboItems() {
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add("Pen");
        items.add("Pencil");
        items.add("Eraser");
        return items;
    }
}

package di;

import common.BaseListCellRenderer;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class ListCellRenderers {
    private ListCellRenderers() {
    }

    public static <T> ListCellRenderer<T> renderer(Function<T, String> stringFunction) {
        return new BaseListCellRenderer<T>() {
            @Override
            protected String getLabelText(T element) {
                return stringFunction.apply(element);
            }
        };
    }
}

package common;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Optional;

public abstract class BaseListCellRenderer<E> extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer<E> {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends E> list, E value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        setColors(list, isSelected);
        setFont(list.getFont());
        setContent(value);
        determineTransparency(list, index);
        return this;
    }

    private void setColors(JList<? extends E> list, boolean isSelected) {
        if (isSelected)
            setSelectionColors(list);
        else
            setRegularColors(list);
    }

    private void setSelectionColors(JList<? extends E> list) {
        setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
        setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
    }

    private void setRegularColors(JList<? extends E> list) {
        setBackground(list.getBackground());
        setForeground(list.getForeground());
    }

    private void setContent(E value) {
        if (value instanceof Icon)
            setIcon((Icon) value);
        else {
            String nullableLabelText = getLabelText(value);
            String labelText = Optional.ofNullable(nullableLabelText).orElse("");
            setText(labelText);
        }
    }

    private void determineTransparency(JList<? extends E> list, int index) {
        boolean shouldBeTransparent = index == -1;
        if (shouldBeTransparent) {
            // note this, the label shouldn't be opaque=true
            setOpaque(false);
            setForeground(list.getForeground());
        } else
            setOpaque(true);
    }

    protected abstract String getLabelText(E element);

    @Override
    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
    }
}

combo, white background
Test 3. Same as Test 2, but without setting Windows L&F
combo, transparent background
It seems new Color(225, 225, 225) is never created or set to a Graphics object (I put breakpoints at the constructor and the setter). I have no clue where it's coming from at all

I do reference the Windows L&F in the demo, but imagine it defaulted to that L&F (rather than set it explicitly)

ComboBox.background key in UIManager class?
